# Does AWS charge for inbound network traffic in lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am designing a solution for something and want to price it out. I have a function I want to deploy as an aws lambda function. It makes 1 api call to an external API (organization w/ a free api) and upserts some data in a database.

What I want to know is, do I pay for the inbound traffic? I have priced out the lambda function execution cost and its basically nothing. But the inbound data would have a ceiling of about 1.2TB/month. Do I pay for that? If the response size is smaller will my bill go down, or if its larger will it go up?

Comment: Pricing reference: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/#Data_Transfer_.26_Other_Charges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pay for the traffic coming "to Lambda". You pay for the traffic coming from "the outside".

If your Lambda runs detached from any VPC, then you pay for every single data transfer.

If your Lambda is running inside VPC, then you pay for the traffic coming from outside of VPC. Transferring data from VPC internal resources to Lambda in the same VPC is free, but you pay for internal API Gateway or internal Application Load Balancer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying... the traffic coming from the outside is indeed what I'm wondering about. Is there anywhere I can calculate this cost? I know aws has some calculators but I'm not exactly sure what im looking for. Perhaps this one? https://calculator.aws/#/addService/VPC

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. Switch the "Data transfer" toggle and put values of the amount of traffic you expect.